# Submit form by using Bootstrap twitter modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, submit, action

I'm trying to submit a form by using the bootstrap modal. I've managed to submit the data successfully at the code that follows. My issue is that I'm working my php by action tags, ie. if($_GET['action']=='add'){//do something} etc. and I'm sending the information by the url. So..at the time being I changed that I make the insertion after checking if the submit button has been submitted that's why the form is working, is there any way I can send the information by the URL and get it inside the modal?   ie. mypage.php?action=add#myModal)

Furthermore, do you know how to prevent the modal to close after submitting, as I want to give the user the ability to add information more than once.
Any help really appreciated.

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
            <th width="275">Name</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="cname" value="" class="input-sm"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" id="save_add" name="save_add" class="btn btn-primary">
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm trying to pass the action and the id on the modal. I've tried all the available solutions provided here but still nothing works for me..Any suggestions are really appreciated!

Comment: Where is your form tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form action="mypage.php" method="get"><table class="table"> <tr> <th width="275">Name</th> <td><input type="text" name="cname" value="" class="input-sm"></td> </tr> </table> </div> </div> <div
 class="modal-footer"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> <input type="submit" value="Save" id="save_add" name="save_add" class="btn btn-primary"> </div></form>
```

Comment: Please note that the snippet is not properly formatted, as the `class="model-footer` section is presented as a plain text. Also it is advisable to add a least some comment as to why your answer is the right answer for the question above.